# i cant get new access token on postman

Tags: asp.net-mvc, imgur

I followed the instructions of imgur api and the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=anfNgyplDjI&t=94s, but when I get a new access token, the same error appears on postman

{"data":{"error":"Too Many Requests","request":"/oauth2/authorize","method":"POST"},"success":false,"status":429}

I also change account, but it still error like this
i hope your guys help me you. Bc i need it early

Answer (score 0):

The error message "Too Many Requests" typically means that you're making requests too frequently, and the server is rate-limiting your access. This could be due to several reasons:

1. Rate Limiting: The Imgur API might have rate limits in place to
   prevent abuse. Make sure you're not exceeding the allowed number of
   requests per minute or hour.
2. Authentication Issues: Ensure that you're properly authenticated
   with the correct access token. If you're using OAuth2, make sure
   your access token is valid and has the necessary scopes.

Comment: 1. i waited from last night to this morning and still error

Comment: 2.well, i followed the instructions of imgur api and this is the first i do this project so i dont know exactly what is it